# nginx location= doesn't work with regular expression

Tags: nginx

Here is my configurations. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

auth_basic doesn't work

```
location = /bitrix/admin/(fileman_admin.php|perfmon_sql_list.php|webdebug_image_profiles.php) {
     satisfy  any; # allow access if authorization is successful

     auth_basic              "admin site";
     auth_basic_user_file    /var/www/my.server/htdocs/mysite/.htpasswd;
}
```

but simultaneously this works:

```
location = /bitrix/admin/fileman_admin.php {..}
```

What is the best way to deny access to

```
site.com/bitrix/admin/fileman_admin.php
site.com/bitrix/admin/perfmon_sql_list.php
site.com/bitrix/admin/webdebug_image_profiles.php
```

Comment: Just for the sake of nitpicking, since the dot in regular expressions matches any char (including the dot) it’s better to escape it `(admin|list|profile)\.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - (none): If no modifiers are present, the location is interpreted as a    prefix match. This means that the location given will be matched 
>     against the beginning of the request URI to determine a match.
> - =: If an equal sign is used, this block will be considered a match if the request URI exactly matches the location given.
> - ~: If a tilde modifier is present, this location will be interpreted    as a case-sensitive regular expression match.
> - ~*: If a tilde and asterisk modifier is used, the location block will    be interpreted as a case-insensitive regular expression match.
> - ^~: If a carat and tilde modifier is present, and if this block is    selected as the best non-regular expression match, regular expression 
>     matching will not take place.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

You must use tilde(`~`) symbol to set regex paths:

```
location ~ ^/bitrix/admin/(fileman_admin.php|perfmon_sql_list.php)$ {
...
}
```